# Rswag specs failing for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, specs, rswag, api-documentation

I am having a very strange issue while documenting the APIs with rswag. I have 15 rswag API documents that has been tested and working fine. But when I run the Rspec for login spec to see If it works or not. It throws an error saying invalid url(error is attached).
And for other APIs the error is invalid method X-API-TOKEN. Although I have handled this on backend for Authorization and X-API-TOKEN. If you guys have faced the similar issue please reach out to this so that I can continue with my deployment process. I've opened the issue on github repo

[image: Error image for rspec]